# Block matrix: collect rectangular ranges to blocks

Tags: matrices

I need to create a matrix filled with blocks spanning different rectangular ranges.

I searched this page and elsewhere but never found a suitable way of doing it. Is there no package that can do that?

This could be an example [image: block matrix[1]]

I am looking for a simple latex package. My idea right now is something such as the following

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{BlockMatrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{BlockM}
  \Block{1}{1}{A}
  \Block{2-1}{3-2}{B}
  \Block{2-3}{3-3}{C}
  \Block{4-2}{4-5}{D}
  \Block{4}{6}{E}
  \Block{4-7}{5-7}{F}
\end{BlockM}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pretty sure Ti*k*Z can do this. Let me fiddle around.

Comment: If you want to have it that simple i suggest u to write your own package for this specific case.

Comment: @user1146332 I might just look into that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I see some strengths of my previous solution, I want to keep it, rather than replace it this with this one.

We define an environment `Blockmatrix` that (almost) behaves as asked. Of course, that definition can be outsourced to a package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Creates a block matrix in which the command \block is defined:
% \block[optional]{from}{from}{to}{to}{content}.
\newenvironment{Blockmatrix}{
    \newcommand{\block}[6][draw]{
        \path[##1] (##3-1, -##2+1) rectangle (##5, -##4) node[pos=0.5] {$##6$};
    }
    \tikzpicture[
        x=4pt+width("C"), y=4pt+height("C"), 
        baseline={([yshift=-1ex]current bounding box.center)}
    ]
}{
    \endtikzpicture
}

\begin{document}
\[
    M = \left(
        \begin{Blockmatrix}
            \block[]{1}{1}{1}{1}{A}
            \block{2}{1}{3}{2}{B}
            \block{2}{3}{3}{3}{C}
            \block{4}{3}{4}{5}{D}
            \block[]{4}{6}{4}{6}{E}
            \block[draw=red]{5}{7}{6}{7}{F}
        \end{Blockmatrix}
    \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(The red box is just an example for what can also be done).

Comment: Thank you alot. I will probably create a package out of that code.

Answer (score 3):

With `nicematrix` there is a special package for cases like this

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2mm}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[
    extra-margin=5pt, columns-width=0.2cm,
    code-after = {\tikz{
            \foreach \bi in {{(2-1)(3-2)}, {(2-3)(3-3)}, {(4-2)(4-4)}, {(5-6)(4-6)}} {
                \node [rectangle, inner xsep=0.2cm, blend mode=multiply, draw, fill=red!20, fit={\bi}] {};
        }}
    }
]
    A              & & & &   & \\
    \Block{2-2}{B} & & \Block{2-1}{C} & &   & \\
                   & & & &   & \\
                   & \Block{1-3}{D} & & & E & \Block{2-1}{F}\\
                   & & & &   & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hoped for a simpler solution.. and the boxes dont have the same linewidths?

Comment: Try to compile the example and you will see that all boxes have the same properties like line width etc. The different line width' are artifacts from the pdf-to-png conversion...

Answer (score 2):

Does the following match your needs?

**Edit:** Code somehow simpliefied.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\[
    \def\p{\phantom{X}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[
            matrix of math nodes, row sep=2pt, column sep=2pt, left delimiter=\{, right delimiter=\}
        ] (m) {
            A  &    &    &    &    &    &\\
            \p & \p & \p &    &    &    &\\
            \p & \p & \p &    &    &    &\\
            \p & \p & \p & \p & \p & E  & \p \\
            \p & \p & \p & \p & \p & \p & \p \\
        };
        \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={pos=.5}]
            \draw (m-2-1.north west) rectangle (m-3-2.south east) node {$B$};
            \draw (m-2-3.north west) rectangle (m-3-3.south east) node {$C$};
            \draw (m-4-3.north west) rectangle (m-4-5.south east) node {$D$};
            \draw (m-4-7.north west) rectangle (m-5-7.south east) node {$F$};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the first part, I created a matrix and gave names to some cells in the matrix. The `\p` (which are `\phantom{...}`) are necessary to take up some space, but without printing anything. The contents of the boxes are printed later, in the `\draw ... rectangle ... node{...}` commands.

Note: I achieved this using [Ti*k*Z](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), a graphics package that is really well documented and extremely flexible. It's definitively worth looking at it!

If one wants to, one can even simplify further and obtain:

```
\[
    \def\p{\phantom{X}}
    \newcommand{\block}[3]{\draw (m-#1.north west) rectangle (m-#2.south east) node[pos=0.5] {$#3$};}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[
            matrix of math nodes, row sep=2pt, column sep=2pt, left delimiter=\{, right delimiter=\}
        ] (m) {
            A  &    &    &    &    &    &\\
            \p & \p & \p &    &    &    &\\
            \p & \p & \p &    &    &    &\\
            \p & \p & \p & \p & \p & E  & \p \\
            \p & \p & \p & \p & \p & \p & \p \\
        };
        \block{2-1}{3-2}{B}
        \block{2-3}{3-3}{C}
        \block{4-3}{4-5}{D}
        \block{5-7}{5-7}{F}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

Alas, I haven't figured out how to get rid of the necessity of the `\p`s I have introduced.

Comment: It does the job but imho it is not as simple as I hoped for. I will wait for a simpler solution but I might accept your answer if no better one will be posted..

Comment: @jack What should a solution you'd be fine with look like?

Comment: I edited my question to show a sample code that I would define as "simple".

Comment: @jack See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

With recent versions of `nicematrix`, here is what you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=2pt}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width=auto,margin]
A                                           \\
\Block[draw]{2-2}{B} && \Block[draw]{2-1}{C} \\
\\
&\Block[draw]{1-4}{D} & & & & E & \Block[draw=red,fill=red!15]{2-1}{F} \\
\\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]